# Display embedded tweets using Blazor Wasm

Tags: twitter, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a DataList that loops through my records and passes the TweetId to a Component where I Invoke a js function to call twttr.widgets.load().

The DataList passes the content without issue but nothing occurs. The HTML is written and the js is fired but the Tweet is not formatted and there are no errors in the console.

My main Component has this code

```
<Tweet TweetId="@media.Url" />
```

TweetComponent

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop

<blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
    <a href="@TweetId"></a>
</blockquote>
@code {

[Inject]
public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public string TweetId { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("CallTwitter", "Invoke Twitter Wrapper");
    }
  }

}
```

Scripts.js

```
function CallTwitter() {
if (typeof (twttr) != 'undefined') {
    twttr.widgets.load();
    console.log("Run 1");
} else {
    $.getScript('https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
    console.log("Run 2");
}

}
```

In my Console, Run 1 is listed 2x

Comment: You need to figure out whether `twttr.widgets.load()` is doing anything - and what it is doing. What do you expect to happen? How does that method know where to load the tweets? Is it fetching the tweets (check the network tab)? Is your component rendering more than once and removing the content added by that method? We can't tell any of this from what you have supplied

Comment: I neglected to indicate that I am using the Twitter https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js loaded in my Index.html.  The info comes from - https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/guides/cms-best-practices.  The network tab does indeed show that there are no outgoing calls occuring.

Comment: move console.log to before twttr.widgets.load &/or change the type check to if(twittr){.. presumably you just want to check if twittr exists (it will return false if undefined), does the console.log get called ?